# How to speed up this Scala solution for a Leetcode problem?

Tags: scala, optimization

I solved easy Leetcode problem [Ransom Note](https://leetcode.com/problems/ransom-note/) in Scala like this :

```
  def canConstruct(ransomNote: String, magazine: String): Boolean = {
    val magazineChars = magazine.toSeq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    val ransomChars = ransomNote.toSeq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    ransomChars.forall { case (c, num) => magazineChars.getOrElse(c, 0) >= num }
  }
```

This solution is Ok but slower than other accepted solutions in Scala.
Now I wonder how to speed it up. How would you suggest optimize this solution ?

Comment: You may use `groupMapReduce` to avoid some intermediate collections and improve the counting. However, IIRC, **Scala** will always be slow in leetcode because they don't apply the same optimizations as with **Java** to only measure hot runs rather than cold starts. - Ah, BTW, I think the `toSeq` is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance purpose, you should use low level data structure (`primitive type` instead of `object type`, `array of primitive type` instead of `List, Map`, i.e.), and low level syntax (`while` instead of `foreach loop`, i.e.)

Here is my solution, which beats 90% ~ 100% (it's random), you can speed up it by replace `foreach` to `while loop` and replace `forall` to `while loop` too, but it's too tedious:

[image]

Comment: BTW: There is one line solution `magazine.diff(ransomNote).size + ransomNote.size == magazine.size` of this problem in scala, and its performance is not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

a slightly optimized version of the above solution:

```scala
  def canConstruct(ransomNote: String, magazine: String): Boolean = {
    if (magazine.length < ransomNote.length) {
      false // if the magazine has fewer letters than the ransom note, then we definitely can't make the note
    } else {
      var i = 0
      val counts = Array.ofDim[Int](26)
      while (i < magazine.length) {
        counts(magazine(i) - 'a') += 1
        if (i < ransomNote.length) counts(ransomNote(i) - 'a') -= 1 // avoid the need for another loop for the ransom note letters
        i += 1
      }

      var c = 0;
      while (c < counts.length) {
        if (counts(c) < 0) {
          return false
        }
        c += 1
      }

      true
    }
  }
```

with the following results (after a few runs):

[image]